# How do I dynamically add option tags in EJS?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I feel like this is sloppy and exactly what EJS tries to prevent.  Is there a way to to add value and options without concatenating a looped string?

```
    <!-- developer field option values -->
    <% var optionstring = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < developers.length; i++){
      optionstring += '<option value="' + developers[i]._id + '">' + developers[i].firstname
    }

    %>



    <% for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){ %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= users[i].firstname %></td> 
        <td><select class="assign_dev"><option value="unassigned">unassigned<%- optionstring %></select></td>
        <td><select class="ticket_status"><option value="open">Open</option><option value="closed">Closed</option></select></td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to avoid concatenating a string, then you can close the code block, insert html, and then reopen the code block.

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){ %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= users[i].firstname %></td> 
        <td>
            <select class="assign_dev">
                <option value="unassigned">unassigned</option>
                <%
                    for (var j = 0; j < developers.length; j++){
                        %><option value="<%= developers[j]._id %>"><%= developers[j].firstname %><%
                    }
                %>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="ticket_status">
                <option value="open">Open</option>
                <option value="closed">Closed</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
%>
```

However, I don't think the real goal should be to avoid concatenation. The goal should be to make the code clear and efficient (as long as efficiency doesn't sacrifice clarity). In my opinion, your original code is better. Since you need to list the same options over and over, creating the list once in the earlier loop and then reusing that cached string in the second loop is more efficient and clearer than a nested loop.

Comment: I also want to to add a default developer value, which I will pull from the database.  I think the way you have listed would be the only way I could do that.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Just tried the code.  It is missing a closing bracket at the bottom.  When I add the closing bracket however, the loop does not iterate.

Comment: When I remove the nested loop, the outer loop iterates.

Comment: @MichaelSpatafore, I didn't realize I had the same `var i` as the loop variable. This was fine when the loops were separate but when they're nested, the inner loop overwrote the outer loop's iterator variable. I fixed the above code to use `j` for the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may fill options in select **without** loop. 
I use Array.prototype.map function for working with each item (see example below)

```
<select id="developer" name="developer">
<option id="0"> Please choose a developer </option>
<% developers.map(item=> { %>
 <option id="<%= item._id%>"> <%= item.firstname %> </option>
<% }) %>
<select>
```

Answer (score 0):

- generating dynamic option and text fields  *

  ```
      <% for(var i = 0; i < filterData.length; i++) { %>
           <select name="hour" >
          <% for(var j = 0; j < filterData.length; j++) { %>
          <option value='<%= filterData[j] %>'><%= filterData[j] %></option>
           <% } %>
        <input type="text" id="sssss">
            </select>
     <% } %>
  ```